# Create Mesh in gap between tiles (in Unity3D)

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, shaders, mesh

I am loading **two kinds of tiles** (meshes in tile format) in Unity, both are placed in the environment correctly but **there is a gap between these two tiles** (see the picture below).  [image]

I want to fill this gap automatically either through `scripting` or a `shader`. With scripting, there is an algorithm I thought of, but its first step is taking too much time.

1. Get each tile and get the outer edges of the mesh (it's taking too much time to calculate with each tile, as there are thousands of tiles)
2. Then raycast from the outer edges of the mesh and get intersection points of outer tiles
3. Take vertices and draw the mesh.

I get stuck in the first steps, as it's taking so much time to calculate the outer edges of a tile. Maybe there is a solution available in form of a `shader` that works in the gaps of two meshes?

Here is visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use the X, Y coordinates and size for your new tile to find the surrounding tiles?

Comment: Yeah maybe a good idea but how do i know the first tile?

Comment: Generating procedural geometry like this can be quite difficult and expensive, and also depends a lot on the shapes of your meshes. Can you show us some examples of the actual meshes you want to join, and what the gap between them looks like? You might be able to modify your tile assets so they don't leave a gap in the first place.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan I'm not sure really. It would depend how you are saving your tiles. Usually when people use uniform tiles they have something like "private Tile[][] tileMap;" in their class. Since yours are non-uniform you probably can't do something as simple, but you may be able to keep two lists, one sorted by x position and one by y position. Then you can do a binary search to find the files nearest the affected area.

Comment: @DMGregory Actually i can't modify the tiles.

Comment: @DMGregory The tiles represent an area of land the other tile represent water of the land

Comment: I can imagine many many ways to make tile meshes that represent water and land. Can you show us what your particular meshes look like, so we know which of those many possibilities to advise you about?

Comment: @DMGregory I tried to mimic the original sceneario in Unity and pictures are updated in the question. I also heard about Delaunay Triangulation. Maybe it will helpful

Comment: Are your meshes really just quads like this? I notice some seem to be shifted around relative to the tile grid — what's the reason for these sideways offsets?

Comment: Well, these quads are approximate representations of original 3d tiles!  we don't have those tiles currently.

Comment: some of the tiles are slightly rotated so that i can resemble the original scenario. As normally the Terran is not on the same height at every location.

Comment: I will updated the tiles infor (images) as i will get the tiles.